# загрузка данных в БД через Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

День добрый, с помощью bash скрипта собираю инвентаризационные сведения о машинах в файл. Хотел бы через python информацию из этого файла залить в БД. Подскажите как правильно это сделать, нужно сначала привести содержимое файла в виде списков, которые потом через цикл добавить в столбы таблицы или как?

Comment: Если ты хочешь сохранять данные в бд postgres, то посмотри библиотеку psycopg2

Comment: не, то как подключатся к разным СУБД и выполнять на них запросы через python я знаю, мне непонятно как в таблицу добавить данные из файла через python.

Comment: Файл формата json?

Comment: нет, текст, пример одной строки: PC343, 192.168.240.22, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3260, DDR3 8040756, SSD Т.е. его надо привести к какому то определенному виду?

Comment: Если данные в формате csv, то даже питон не нужен. Можно загрузить с помощью `psql` командой `\copy`, типа `\copy mytable(field1, field2, field3, ...) from '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV`. Предварительно создать таблицу с полями соответствующих типов, как в csv файле.